# How to wrap a number between 0 and 1

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap any number to be between 0 and 1. (just like using modulo `%` for integers)

For example,

`wrap(0.99)` should return `0.99`.

`wrap(1.04)` should return `0.04`.

`wrap(12)` should return `0`.

Is there any built-in function that can do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JS Numbers are represented as double-precision values, so `1.04%1` would already work.

[MDN: Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

> The Number JavaScript object is a wrapper object allowing you to work with numerical values. A Number object is created using the Number() constructor. A primitive type object number is created using the Number() function.

```js
console.log(0.99%1)
console.log(1.04%1)
console.log(12%1)
```

[MDN: Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)

Comment: Wow I didn't know `%` also works for floating numbers in JS. Thanks!

Comment: Note that because of the normal floating-point rounding issues `1.04%1` may actually return `0.040000000000000036`. To avoid this, you can do something like this `parseFloat((1.04%1).toFixed(2))`.

Comment: Proper rounding is done mathematically, not with strings.  `Math.round(value * 100) / 100`  (for 2 decimals places). Of course if one doesn't already have a proper generic "roundTo(n)" function in their arsenal this would be a good time to add one.

Answer (score 1):

None that I can find, but couldn't you just do:

```
n = n - Math.floor(n);
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try using x-Math.floor(x);
for negative numbers you may want to use x-Math.ciel(x);
based on your requirements.